# Trying to get my TapGestureRecognizer to close my side bar menu only

Tags: xcode, swift, sidebar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I created a side bar to open when I use the UISwipeGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer in swift. It works but for some reason its not letting click any side bar table cells. As soon as I click anywhere around the app it closes my sidebar. I'm trying to get it to close only when I click outside of the side bar menu and still access my table cells. This is the code that I've written. Let me know if you need more info! Thanks!

I'm filling my side bar table in my UIViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {

    var sideBar:SideBar = SideBar()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
// Side bar action and text
        sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Home", "Business Directory", "Classifieds", "Featured News", "Jobs", "Restaurants", "Sports"])
        sideBar.delegate = self
}

// SideBar selections
    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {
        if index == 0{
            println("You clicked the home label")
        } else if index == 1{
            println("You clicked the business label")
        }
    }
```

I'm calling the functionality in my SideBar.swift file

```
let tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "Tapped:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        originView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

func Tapped(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 1{
            showSideBar(false)
            delegate?.sideBarWillClose?()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sidebar is a subview of originView, the tap gesture recognizer is triggered even if you click on your sidebar.

You should add sidebar ABOVE your originView in order to prevent the sidebar to react to UITapGestureRecognizer.